# Place values inside bootstrap modal popup field value in spring MVC using ajax to get the data from database

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc

I need to get the values from database inside the modal popup field in spring MVC using ajax. I think, we need to place the values inside modal popup field using javascript.

Help highly appreciated!!!!...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following javascript code to make ajax call and place the values in the field

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function ajaxLink(url, params, displayComponentId) {
                    $.post(url, params, function(data) {
                        document.getElementById('fieldId').value =data.name;
                    });
                }
        function onClickMethod(val){
            ajaxLink('/myProject/getTags', {'tagName': val}, 'viewDiv');
        }
</script>
```

The fieldId is should be the id of the corresponding field.

Inside the server side you have to follow below code in spring MVC

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getTags", method = RequestMethod.POST) 
@ResponseBody  public  User getTags(@RequestParam("tagName") String
tagName) 
{
        User user=new User();
        //Write a method to access the data from DB
        user.setName("test")
        return user;  
 }
```

Try it. It works for me with spring MVC + Bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

You can try to invoke your custom url inside the modal like this:

```
function load_modal(ev){
    if (ev && ev.preventDefault)
        ev.preventDefault(); // prevent navigation
    var url = "" //construct your url with all parameters that you need
    //avoid cache
    url +="&_="+(new Date()).getTime()
    $("#modal").load(url, function() { // load the url into the modal
          $(this).modal('show'); // display the modal on url load
    });
    return false; // prevent the click propagation
}
```

That url invokes the action in your server-side and populate the data that you need in the result page that will be displayed in the modal